# W8 QL2300i.Sys corrupted

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, boot, bsod

I've a problem with my windows 8 installation. When I try to boot it goes in an automatic repair loop and then it bsod's and goes again. The BSOD goes to fast to read it.

So I put a installation disk in it (W8.1 I had somewhere). So I booted up with that and it gave me a screen with 9 options to do stuff (like enter safe mode, disable auto reboot after bsod). Nothing really seemed to work. Also I got a bluescreen somewhere in this process with the `QL2300(i).sys` corrupted error. (`Status: 0xc0000098 code)`.

After that bluescreen windows told me to put the correct dvd in (W8 Pro X64 nl) and go to repair mode. So I burned the correct version to dvd from MSDN and put that in. It kept cirkeling for a while like the normal w8 boot and after that it restarted again with nothing fixed.

On a dutch forum someone recommended me to do a disk check. So I booted up with ubuntu live cd and checked for bad sectors. After ~35mins nothing found on the 160GB disk.

Questions:
- Does someone recognize this problem and know where the problem is?
- Can I delete my windows partitions (after back-upping data) and reinstall my windows?

Thanks for help,

Comment: For everyone with some kind of this problem: My ram module was defect. I installed windows XP (because it can actually install with defective ram.., sometimes). And did a memtest from : http://hcidesign.com/memtest/

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.
Firstly, consider if your data on the partition is really that important that you need to keep hold of, if this is the case then a fresh installation and clean format would be of last resort.

Next option is to continue from what you did with a linux live boot CD. Try to get into your partition from within the Live CD and rescue your files/data that way.

Another tool which is a seperate Linux live disk is called GParted. (http://gparted.org/faq.php)  you can get into your OS and rebuild any bad sections of your NTFS partition and try to rescue it that way.

Research your BSOD error code and see what you can dig up.

This may wiki page will help > http://www.wiki-errors.com/wiki-errors.php?wiki=0xc0000098

> The 0xc0000098 error is the Hexadecimal format of the error caused. This is common
> error code format used by windows and other windows compatible software and driver
> vendors.
>
> This code is used by the vendor to identify the error caused. This 0xc0000098 error
> code has a numeric error number and a technical description. In some cases the error
> may have more parameters in 0xc0000098 format .This additional hexadecimal code are
> the address of the memory locations where the instruction(s) was loaded at the time of
> the error.

Also check this > h--p://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=3590

you could also try to manually re-copy over the affected file from the original MSDN image and replace it to see if this resolves your problem, this can be achieved via a Linux Live CD method.
A problem may arise as windows digitally signs certain system files and drivers which could disallow any new replacement files which you try to restore from MS win8 OS. disk/image.

Comment: Formatted the disk. Able to run install now (windows 7). Crashes with http://www.wiki-errors.com/wiki-errors.php?wiki=0x80070570 error code

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was a defective ram module.

After format recommend `majika` i installed windows 7. That didnt worked. Tried windows XP and it installed. Still some weird issues were occuring. After that I did a memtest from: http://hcidesign.com/memtest/

Before it started scanning for errors it gave a lot of errors. I pulled one memory module out and after that the other one. So I found out which one was defective.

Hope that it helps poeple later